# What are Ancestry DNA tests telling me?

Tags: dna

I had my DNA as well as my husbands DNA done.

Does the test do both Maternal and paternal?

The reason that I ask, is several people in my husband's family have also had DNA tests done and they don't appear to be a match.

I received his results from GED that I had done off of Ancestory.com and there are no names in his family that match at all?

Comment: I think I understand that you had DNA tests done for yourself and your husband at Ancestry.com but none of your husband's family who have also had tests done there are showing as matches for him -- can you confirm I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: Nicki - there are many different types of DNA tests. It's impossible to answer your question without you saying what specific DNA test you had done. You can add details to your question using the [edit] button below your post.

Answer (score 4):

Ancestry DNA does autosomal tests. The test looks at all branches of the family, maternal and paternal, and is very reliable in detecting cousins out to at least 3rd cousins.

If your husband has known relatives who have DNA tested but don't show matches, then I can think of three possible reasons:

1. Maybe the cousins tested at another company, not AncestryDNA, but FamilyTreeDNA or 23andMe or somewhere else.
2. Maybe AncestryDNA made a mistake with your husband's sample (it does happen) and results got mixed up, or
3. Maybe your husband is not actually blood-related to the cousins because of an unknown adoption or hospital mix-up (wrong baby) or a case of infidelity by his parent or grandparent.